# Gradle sync failed: connection refused by remote host

Tags: gradle

I am working with Android Studio 1.4 with a Japanese OS . I am trying to begin a new project, but I get this message:

```
Gradle sync failed: 既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました。
     Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

I'm not sure what the exact error message is in English, but it says "existing connection closed by remote host (forcibly)." I tried turning off my firewall and making sure nothing is blocking Android Studio from connecting, but no luck. I'm not sure what the exact  I'm a beginner and it's probably something simple, but if someone could help me with this I would appreciate it. Thank you.